# Авторизация пользователя Facebook вручную

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-api

Отправляю первоначальный запрос

```
$params = array(
'client_id'     => $client_id,
'redirect_uri'  => $redirect_uri,
'response_type' => 'code',
'scope'         => 'email'
);
echo $url . '?' . urldecode(http_build_query($params));
```

Затем делаю:

```
  $params = array(
  'client_id' => $client_id,
  'redirect_uri' => $redirect_uri,
  'client_secret' => $client_secret,
  'code' => $_GET['code']  
);

   $query = http_build_query($params);
   $url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?$query";

   $ch = curl_init();

   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url. '?' . http_build_query($params));
   $res = curl_exec($ch);
   curl_close($ch);
```

Командой `print_r($res)` смотрю что возвращает. Возвращает ошибку

```
{
 "error": {
     "message"    : "This IP can't make requests for that application.",
     "type"       : "OAuthException",
     "code"       : 5,
     "fbtrace_id" : "Gs63EOTMl81"
 }
}
```

Как мне эту сложность победить?

Причем вставляю сформированный урл в браузер все работает, выдает token.

Comment: Посмотрите тут http://stackoverflow.com/q/12072720/5441700

Comment: Спасибо все заработало.